# Is it possible to see all the open browser tabs? (client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have 5 browser tabs open. google.com, stackoverflow.com, MYSITE: About page, MYSITE: price page, MYSITE: home page.

Is there a JS method to see what tabs are open? Ideally it would return an array or object? e.g.:

```
[{tab: 1, title: 'google'},
 {tab: 2, title: 'stackoverflow'},
 {tab: 3, title: 'MYSITE: About'},
 {tab: 4, title: 'MYSITE: Price'},
 {tab: 5, title: 'MYSITE: Home'}]
```

I ask this because I have noticed on some sites checkout process that says something like "Are you sure you are done shopping because you have other tabs open"? How do they know that? *(I can think of a server side way with sessions but is their an easy client side way to achieve this?)*

Comment: You can use tricks (like updating cookies) to get tabs of **your domain**, but being able to list all open tabs would be a massive privacy leak.

Comment: By tricks you mean server side session tracking and crafty cookies right? I'll check out a link if you have something to share

Comment: I suppose there could be some client-side cookie updating mechanism involving `setInterval` (like if the cookie stops updating it means the user closed the corresponding tab). But it's just speculation, maybe there are better ways.

Comment: I've seen something like a heartbeat.js file that shoots off a request at `setInterval`. Server side I believe it updates the session with the path of the page from which it was fired. I'm quite sure cookies aren't involved at all.

Comment: @f1f5 That's not possible, unless you browse through a proxy which exposes an API that allows you to query that information or that you are developing a browser extension.

Comment: I think using sessionStorage would be a better idea, but yes, indeed you can only see tabs from your domain.

Comment: @plalx Yeah from a security/privacy perspective I get your point.